# Web Service Transaction Control

Tags: java, transactions

I'm working on some remote api invoking recently. This is the background.

In a transaction, let's say a payment workflow, after the customer finished his payment successfully through paypal api, I need to update my local db (let's say update order_table, update score_table).

It would be like this:

Whole Transaction
{
invoking paypal api - success
update order_table - success
update score_table - failed
}

If the invoking paypal api is a local method invoking like update xxx_table, it would be very straightforward, the whole transaction will rollback, but in a remote api invoking, I just can't rollback it.

Here comes the question, do we have a universal solutions for this case?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: So the question is how to roll back the call of the paypal api? AFAIK you'd have to do the rollback yourself, e.g. by hooking into the callback for transaction rollback.

Comment: @Thomas, well, I use paypal to demonstrate the case. How to do transaction control in web service invoking would be more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

If the webservices are under your control you could use something like [JBoss WS-Transactions](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Transactions_Administrators_Guide/ch05.html) or something similar, depending on your environment.

When accessing third party webservices it depends on whether they provide a functionality like that, if not you'd have to do the rollback yourself.

Besides that distributed transactions might cause more problems than they solve so you should carefully think about whether you really need them.